# No truthful answer?

Tags: logical-deduction, wordplay

Here is your challenge; Formulate a yes or no question that cannot be answered without lying.... I have written one such question but there may be more..Good luck.

Remember, the answer to the question must be restricted to yes or no.

Comment: Are you...No???

Comment: Is the correct answer to this question "No"?

Comment: We have done it tons of times and I am sure another try won't cost much

Comment: Gamow, you have almost exactly the same one I wrote, Good Job!!!

Comment: @Xcoder555 Be aware that questions with multiple answers tend to be closed, and fairly quickly. This question comes across as a "guess what answer I'm thinking of," and these types of questions are poorly received (see http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4573/what-exactly-is-too-broad).  

You can either try to revamp this question to limit possible responses, but either way please stick around and continue to contribute. We will help you refine and create high-quality puzzles.

Comment: Did I kiss you more than twice? `(Assuming I didn't kiss you before.)`

Comment: @Aggie Kid I don't quite know what I would do to fix this question, but I will use what you said for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short list of possible answers:

> Will you answer this question "No"?
>
>  Is the correct answer to this question "No"? (from [Gamow](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/8874/gamow))
>
>  Will you answer this with "No"?

Comment: Good job Aggie Kidd!